# For XML Custom Attribute and Element in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2016, for-xml-path

I need to create a following XML with Custom Element with attribute using Hard-code data.

Table schema: **StudentMark**:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StudentMark]
(
    [StudentMarkId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StudentId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [SubjectId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Score] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ScoreInfo] [xml] NOT NULL,
    [GeneratedOn] [datetime2](2) NOT NULL,
    [IsPass] [bit] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_StudentMark] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([StudentMarkId] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Sample seed data

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[StudentMark] ([StudentId], [SubjectId], [ScoreInfo], [GeneratedOn], [Score], [IsPass])
VALUES ('FC3CB475-B480-4129-9190-6DE880E2D581', '0D72F79E-FB48-4D3E-9906-B78A9D105081', '<StudentMarkAttribute xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></StudentMarkAttribute>', '2017-08-10 10:10:15', 95, 1),
       ('0F4EF48C-93E3-41AA-8295-F6B0E8D8C3A2', '0D72F79E-FB48-4D3E-9906-B78A9D105081', '<StudentMarkAttribute xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></StudentMarkAttribute>', '2017-08-10 10:10:15', 100, 1),
       ('0F4EF48C-93E3-41AA-8295-F6B0E8D8C3A2', 'AB172272-D2E9-49E1-8040-6117BB6743DB', '<StudentMarkAttribute xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></StudentMarkAttribute>', '2017-08-16 09:06:20', 25, 0),
       ('FC3CB475-B480-4129-9190-6DE880E2D581', 'AB172272-D2E9-49E1-8040-6117BB6743DB', '<StudentMarkAttribute xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></StudentMarkAttribute>', '2017-08-16 09:06:20', 82, 1);
```

**Requirement**: I need to add a Element `<DigitallySigned>` in the XML, The XML is for one Record using the where clause `WHERE [StudentMarkId] = 1`. Kindly see the following Template, the attribute `DateSigned` is exactly the same `dateTime` of element `GeneratedOn` and the value of the Element `Admin` is a hard-coded value.

**XML Template**:

```
<ScoreInfo>
    <DigitallySigned DateSigned="2017-08-10 10:10:15">Admin</DigitallySigned>
    <StudentMarkId>1</StudentMarkId>
    <StudentId>FC3CB475-B480-4129-9190-6DE880E2D581</StudentId>
    <SubjectId>0D72F79E-FB48-4D3E-9906-B78A9D105081</SubjectId>
    <Score>95</Score>
    <GeneratedOn>2017-08-10 10:10:15</GeneratedOn>
    <IsPass>1</IsPass>
</ScoreInfo>
```

I tried the following code

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
    (SELECT SM.[GeneratedOn] AS [DateSigned] FOR XML RAW)
      ,SM.[StudentMarkId]
      ,SM.[StudentId]
      ,SM.[SubjectId]
      ,SM.[Score]
      ,SM.[GeneratedOn]
      ,SM.[IsPass]
  FROM [DevDB].[dbo].[StudentMark] SM
  WHERE SM.[StudentMarkId] = 1
  FOR XML RAW ('ScoreInfo'), ELEMENTS
```

I got the following XML output

```
<ScoreInfo>&lt;row DateSigned="2017-08-10T10:10:15"/&gt;<StudentMarkId>1</StudentMarkId><StudentId>FC3CB475-B480-4129-9190-6DE880E2D581</StudentId><SubjectId>0D72F79E-FB48-4D3E-9906-B78A9D105081</SubjectId><Score>95</Score><GeneratedOn>2017-08-10T10:10:15</GeneratedOn><IsPass>1</IsPass></ScoreInfo>
```

Kindly assist me how to get the required `XML`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here goes.

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [GeneratedOn] AS "DigitallySigned/@DateSigned",
    'Admin' AS "DigitallySigned"
      ,SM.[StudentMarkId]
      ,SM.[StudentId]
      ,SM.[SubjectId]
      ,SM.[Score]
      ,SM.[GeneratedOn]
      ,SM.[IsPass]
  FROM [DevDB].[dbo].[StudentMark] SM
  WHERE SM.[StudentMarkId] = 1
  FOR XML PATH ('ScoreInfo');
```